# Centos 8, PHP 7.2 and MS Sql Server

Tags: pdo, centos, php-7.2, unixodbc, centos8

I am planning moving on to the Centos 8 but it seems that I cannot get a working PDO connection with SQL server using just plain Centos 8 packages.

I have installed the unixODBC packages and after that from PECL sqlsrv and sqlsrv_pdo but I can't figure out how to make the actual connection or odbc configuration.

As most of my code to be transferred to the new environments is written using PDO, I wouldn't want to change it to sql server native.

Are there any step-by-step instructions how to build PDO ODBC connection to sql server without using freetds, which isn't available through the centos repositories (or RHEL either).

Comment: Could you please update with how you resolved this (assuming Pierre's answer worked)? He lists what packages to install and ini files to edit, but not how to use this environment in php with a PDO query.  I have a similar but different problem with same env: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67170980/login-timeout-expired-with-pdo-sqlsrv-connection-able-to-query-with-tsql-just-f

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue and I solved it as follow:

```
sudo dnf install php-pear
sudo dnf install php-devel
sudo dnf install make
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo dnf install unixODBC-devel
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

then:

```
sudo nano /etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini
```

Add in the file 30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini:

```
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

then:

```
sudo nano /etc/php.d/20-sqlsrv.ini
```

Add in the file 20-sqlsrv.ini:

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
```

Download and install msodbcsql17-17.4.2.1-1.x86_64.rpm from https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/8/prod/

```
sudo yum install msodbcsql17-17.4.2.1-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Then just need to restart php-fpm

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

Good luck!

Comment: if you see an error: sql.h compilation terminated, make dnf install unixODBC-devel

Comment: I'm having trouble getting a working connection to my SQL Server.  I've followed everything in your answer here.  I'm also able to query the remote SQL Server using `tsql`.  How do I use all of this in forming a working PDO connection?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67170980/login-timeout-expired-with-pdo-sqlsrv-connection-able-to-query-with-tsql-just-f

Comment: I resolved this issue and gave examples of how to use in PDO at the link right above, in case anyone else was stuck like I was.

Comment: pecl/sqlsrv requires PHP (version >= 8.0.0), installed version is 7.2.24