# Login timeout expired with PDO sqlsrv connection. Able to query with TSQL just fine from same RHEL 8 client

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, pdo, rhel8

I'm getting "Login timeout expired" with the following connection attempt:

```
$dbx = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=RemoteSQLServer;Database=TheDatabase", SQL_USER, SQL_PW);
```

If I add LoginTimeout:

```
$dbx = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=RemoteSQLServer;Database=TheDatabase;LoginTimeout=60;", SQL_USER, SQL_PW);
```

The script returns a Bad Gateway error. I'm at my wits end and am unsure what I'm missing. Details below.

This is a RHEL 8.3 system with PHP 7.4.6 installed. RemoteSQLServer is a remote Windows system running SQLServer 2012. I'm able to successfully connect just to this instance from a RHEL 7 system with php-mssql (which isn't available in RHEL 8 as far as I can tell).

To hopefully rule out any network issues, I'm able to connect to RemoteSQLServer using `tsql` from the RHEL 8 client with zero problem.

```
[user@rhel8client ~]# tsql -S RemoteSQLServer -U SQL_USER
Password: 
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1> select getdate();
2> go

Apr 19 2021 08:32:06:467PM
(1 row affected)
1> quit
[user@rhel8client ~]#
```

Related phpinfo details:

```
[user@rhel8client ~]# php -i | grep sqlsrv
/etc/php.d/20-sqlsrv.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-sqlsrv.ini,
Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, compress.bzip2, phar, sqlsrv
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite, sqlsrv
pdo_sqlsrv
pdo_sqlsrv support => enabled
pdo_sqlsrv.client_buffer_max_kb_size => 10240 => 10240
pdo_sqlsrv.log_severity => 0 => 0
pdo_sqlsrv.report_additional_errors => 1 => 1
pdo_sqlsrv.set_locale_info => 2 => 2
sqlsrv
sqlsrv support => enabled
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize => 10240 => 10240
sqlsrv.LogSeverity => 0 => 0
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems => 0 => 0
sqlsrv.SetLocaleInfo => 2 => 2
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors => On => On
```

ini files above:

```
[user@rhel8client ~]# cat /etc/php.d/20-sqlsrv.ini
extension=sqlsrv.so

[user@rhel8client ~]# cat /etc/php.d/30-sqlsrv.ini
extension=sqlsrv.so

[user@rhel8client ~]# cat /etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini
extension=sqlsrv.so
```

Related installed packages:

```
[user@rhel8client ~]# yum list installed | grep msodb
msodbcsql17.x86_64                            17.7.2.1-1                               @System   

[user@rhel8client ~]# yum list installed | grep ODBC
unixODBC.x86_64                               2.3.7-1.el8                              @rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms        
unixODBC-devel.x86_64                         2.3.7-1.el8                              @rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms 

[user@rhel8client ~]# pecl list
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package    Version State
pdo_sqlsrv 5.9.0   stable
sqlsrv     5.9.0   stable
```

This [post from 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181436/centos-8-php-7-2-and-ms-sql-server) asks a similar question but lone answer appears to leave out details on what to do after installing the packages they list (I've done that much see above).

I'm not sure what else I need to do here.

Is there any way to get PDO to use tsql?

Comment: Perhaps you have an old ODBC driver trying to connect to a new SQL Server, or a new ODBC driver trying to connect to an old SQL Server? Please edit your question to include... 1. What version of "ODBC Driver nn for SQL Server" do you have installed? 2. What version of Microsoft SQL Server are you trying to connect to?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Updated post with requested (and additional) information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured how to get a working connection from a RHEL8 machine to a Windows system running SQL Server 2012.  This [how-to](https://x-team.com/blog/using-ms-sql-dynamic-ports-in-php-7-with-odbc/) was helpful.

First install a few needed packages

```
sudo dnf install php-odbc freetds freetds-devel
```

Go to your SQL Server 2012 machine and grab these variables:

```
SELECT @@servername AS 'Server Name'; # MYSERVERNAME
SELECT @@servicename AS 'Instance Name'; # MSSQLSERVER
```

Issue this from prompt to get the `libtdsodbc.so.0` path

```
ldconfig -p | grep libtdsodbc

[user@rhel8 ~]# ldconfig -p | grep libtdsodbc
->  libtdsodbc.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
    libtdsodbc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libtdsodbc.so
```

Edit `/etc/odbcinst.ini` and change the `FreeTDS` section to the following:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS Driver
Driver = /lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
# save & exit
```

Edit `/etc/odbc.ini` -- this ini file defines DSN's.  Note that it may be blank to start with, that is OK

```
[ArbitraryServerID]
Description = AppDatabase database on MYSERVERNAME
Driver = FreeTDS
Database = AppDatabase
ServerName = ArbitraryServerID
TDS_Version = 8.0
# save and exit
```

NOTE: "ArbitraryServerID" can be any string - just use it consistently across all of your configs

Edit `/etc/freetds.conf` to add the following section

```
[ArbitraryServerID]
        host = mysqlserver.example.com
        # host = 1.2.3.4
        instance = MYSQLSERVER
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
        text size = 64512
        client charset = UTF-8
```

The connection can now be tested using isql

```
isql -S ArbitraryServerID -U 'username' -P 'password'
```

Assuming that works OK, restart `php-fpm`

```
service php-fpm restart
```

In your PHP application, the PDO connection string should look something like:

```
$mssql_server   = 'ArbitraryServerID';
$mssql_user     = 'username';
$mssql_pw       = 'password';
$dbx_mssql = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVERNAME=$mssql_server;Database=AppDatabase", $mssql_user, $mssql_pw);
```

That's it, you now have working ODBC connection to a remote SQLServer instance.