# CentOS and pdo_sqlsrv for PHP 7.2 - how to install (PLESK)

Tags: php, sql-server, centos, sqlsrv, plesk-onyx

I am hosting a site that needs to connect to SQL Server.

My PHP 7.2 is missing `pdo_sqlsrv` - how to install it and make it work?

I was trying that solution: [Centos 8, PHP 7.2 and MS Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181436/centos-8-php-7-2-and-ms-sql-server)
but pecl/sqlsrv requires PHP (version >= 8.0.0) and I need 7.2

Answer (score 1):

Install the msodbcsql package:

```
# curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
# yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel
# ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql18
```

Install necessary packages:

```
# yum install unixODBC-devel make gcc-c++ gcc autoconf automake plesk-php72-devel libtool-ltdl.x86_64 libtool-ltdl-devel.x86_64
```

Add the pdo_sqlsrv and sqlsrv-5.8.1 modules:

```
# /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-5.8.1
# echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" > /opt/plesk/php/7.2/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
# /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/pecl install sqlsrv-5.8.1
# echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" > /opt/plesk/php/7.2/etc/php.d/sqlsrv.ini
```

Reread PHP handlers:

```
# plesk bin php_handler --reread
```

Reread the components properties to make modules visible in GUI:

```
# plesk sbin packagemng -sdf
```

Make sure that the required modules are enabled:

```
# /opt/plesk/php/X.X/bin/php -m | grep sqlsrv
pdo_sqlsrv
sqlsrv
```

Restart the PHP-FPM master process to apply changes to FPM sites

Solution from [PLESK](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/12377482190999--How-to-install-the-sqlsrv-extension-for-the-Plesk-PHP-handlers-)